# Java: Clickable grid project - what to use? (JFrames & JPanels)?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I'm currently getting started on a project where I use a grid for a game (Dot game, but that's not very important). Basically, it will be a grid of dots, where a player can click on the lines between the dots (like [this](https://www.wikihow.com/images/thumb/8/83/Win-at-the-Dot-Game-Step-10.jpg/aid608874-v4-728px-Win-at-the-Dot-Game-Step-10.jpg)).

[image]

I currently am using a `JFrame`, and was thinking about ways I could populate it with `JPanel` components to create clickable regions. Currently, I was thinking about trying to create for loops to correctly populate it, but I don't know how I could efficiently do this.

Any recommendations for how to do this? I'm not asking people to write code for me, just point me in the right direction. Is there any layout (`GridLayout`?) that would work well for this?

Answer (score 0):

Welp, I ended up figuring it out on my own, but using a soulution not quite ideal. I have a for loop making every odd line have a black panel, then clickable jbutton, then a black panel, etc. Every even line has a clickable j button, then a white middle pannel, then a clickable jbutton, etc. 
Looks like this:

https://gyazo.com/79b80dfe13b017a234e6fad2aa224d58

Comment: This will kill performance. I’d try to find a solution that uses only one panel and detects clicks x;y coordinantes. And accommodate some image in the right place.